# Get Dates between Ranges, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've two dates

> 1. 21/01/2011 [From Date]
> 2. 25/01/2011 [To Date]

How can I get all the dates between these ranges using c#

The answer should be

> 21/01/2011
>  22/01/2011
>   23/01/2011
>  24/01/2011
>   25/01/2011

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                         .Select(x => fromDate.Date.AddDays(x))
                         .TakeWhile(x => x <= toDate.Date);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this can help you:
http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2007/03/01/CSharpCodeToGetGenericListOfDatesBetweenStartingAndEndingDate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
var dateArr = new List<DateTime>();

for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1)) {
   dateArr.Add(date);
}
```

Now **dateArr** contains your required dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesBetween(
    DateTime start,
    DateTime end
    )
{
    DateTime current = start;
    while (current <= end) 
    {
        yield return current.Date;
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

should do the job

*[edit] Added the `.Date` to "round" the date to midnigth*

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
        var startDT = new DateTime(2011, 01, 21);
        var endDT = new DateTime(2011, 01, 25);
        var workDT = startDT;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(workDT.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            workDT = workDT.AddDays(1);
        } while (workDT <= endDT);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if we have anything to do this inbuilt in Framework but you can try this:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2011,01,21);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2011,01,25);
List<DateTime> datetimerange = new List<DateTime>();
while(DateTime.Compare(dt1,dt2) <= 0)
{
        datetimerange.Add(dt1);
        dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (toDate < fromDate)
  return;

var days = (new DateTime[(toDate - fromDate).Days + 1).
             Select((x, i) => fromDate.AddDays(i));
```